# Azure table storage failover using NodeJs SDK

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, failover

I have configured an Azure Table Storage account to be RA-GRS and used the following code to access it:

```
const host = {
    primaryHost: `https://${primaryAccountName}.table.core.windows.net`,
    secondaryHost: `https://${primaryAccountName}-secondary.table.core.windows.net`
  };
var tableSvc = azure.createTableService(primaryAccountName, accessKey, host);
const entGen = azure.TableUtilities.entityGenerator;
const locationMode = azure.StorageUtilities.LocationMode;
const tableName = 'testTable';

  const options = {
    locationMode: locationMode.PRIMARY_THEN_SECONDARY,
    requestLocationMode: locationMode.PRIMARY_THEN_SECONDARY
   };
  tableSvc.retrieveEntity(tableName, 'hometasks', '1', options, function(error, result, response){
    if(error){
      console.log('Error on retrieveEntity!', error, result, response);
    } else {
      console.log('Entity retrieved', result.published._);
    }
  });
```

I initiated failover manually and expected once the failover is finished, it picks up the new account and keeps working but it didn't and failed with the following error:

> Error on retrieveEntity! Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
> test0failover-secondary.table.core.windows.net

Is there any way to achieve a smooth transition to the secondary account? What I am looking for is having read access to the secondary account while failover happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because once you to a manual failover, after the failover is complete your storage account becomes locally-redundant (LRS). You will have to manually convert that account to geo-redundant (RAGRS or GRS).

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-portal#important-implications-of-account-failover):

> **After the failover, your storage account type is automatically
> converted to locally redundant storage (LRS) in the new primary
> region. You can re-enable geo-redundant storage (GRS) or read-access
> geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS) for the account.** Note that converting
> from LRS to GRS or RA-GRS incurs an additional cost. For additional
> information, see Bandwidth Pricing Details.
>
> After you re-enable GRS for your storage account, Microsoft begins
> replicating the data in your account to the new secondary region.
> Replication time is dependent on the amount of data being replicated.

Comment: True but not great, so I have to update my client application code until I re-enable geo-redundancy.